# java read encoded data from database and create pdf file

Tags: java, pdf

I am reading encoded data from database. When I decode data I get something like 
%PDF-1.3
23 Obj
xref
10000000 123n
.
.
.
.
%EOF

I am guessing it's a metadata of PDF file with data. My question is how do I create PDF file out of this with readable data only.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to know what the data in DB represents. I would suggest to connect to the database using a general client. For example, for Oracle - SqlDeveloper, for MS Sql Server - Visual Sql Server, etc

Display the table which has a column of type `long`, `clob` or `blob` and try to save it to a file. Name the file with an extension `.pdf`. Try to open the saved file and see if it gets open correctly by a pdf reader.

If this is a case, saving it from Java is trivial. For example: http://www.astral-consultancy.co.uk/cgi-bin/hunbug/doco.cgi?11120

Comment: DB used in Sql Server.. Datatype for this column is text , If I am not wrong text corresponds to CLOB/varchar(max) . If I save data from DB directly into a file It will not make any sense because data in DB is encoded.

Comment: Ok, it's a good starter. Try decoding the textual data to an array of bytes and then save it to a file with a `.pdf` extension. Do not try to parse the byte array. Most probably it's a valid pdf file.